# Counting the number of distinct greatest common divisors for an integer.

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

What is the expression for the number of distinct greatest common divisors possible for the number $N$?  Let us say that $N$ is composed of 4 prime numbers $N = p_3 p_2 p_1 p_0$.  Now if $p_i$ are all unique, I think the answer is
$$
C = \sum_{i = 0}^4 {4 \choose i}
$$
I can also tell that there are less than this if a prime repeats, say $p_3 = p_2$ (by enumerating by hand).

Comment: what do you mean by gcd of a number?

Comment: Do you just mean 'divisors'?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function

Comment: I meant 'divisors' but my original issue was trying to calculate the maximum possible number of greatest common divisors between a number $N$ and a different positive integer (knowing nothing of this second integer), which turns out to be equivalent to asking the number of distinct positive divisors of $N$, or so it appears from the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are essentially asking for the number of positive divisors of $N$. If
$$N=p_1^{a_1}p_2^{a_2}\cdots p_n^{a_n},$$
where the $p_i$ are distinct primes, the number of positive divisors of $N$ is
$$(a_1+1)(a_2+1)\cdots(a_n+1).$$

For to make a positive divisor of $N$, we first sit in front of the prime $p_1$, and decide how many copies of $p_1$ the positive divisor will get. Our choices are $0$, $1$, and so on up to $a_1$, a total of $a_1+1$ choices. Now we sit in front of $p_2$, and decide on how many copies of $p_2$ the divisor will get. There are $a_2+1$ choices. And so on.

The result uses the fact that any positive integer has an essentially unique representation as a product of prime powers.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you just mean "number of divisors" rather than "common divisors", then the number is just $16 = 2^4$, which can be seen from the fact that each subset of $\{p_0, p_1, p_2, p_3\}$ give rise to a distinct divisor of their product.

Your expression has the same value, as can be seen by expanding $(1+1)^4$ by the binomial theorem.

In the general case with $N$ distinct prime factors, you get the answer $2^N$ by exactly the same process.

If you have some repeated factors then you should look at the answer provided by André Nicolas, or look up [Divisor Function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) on Wikipedia.

Note that to answer your question about the greatest number of distinct divisors of $N$, the greatest number will always be attained when all the prime factors of $N$ are distinct, since if they are not distinct, then some of the subsets of $\{p_0, p_1, \dots,p_n\}$ will give rise to the same divisors of $N$.

For example, if $N=pq$ then the subsets of $\{p,q\}$ are $\emptyset, \{p\}, \{q\}, \{p,q\}$ leading to the factors $1, p, q, pq$, whereas if $p=q$, (so that $N=p^2$) then the factors are $1, p, p, p^2$ which are not all distinct, so you get 3 factors instead of the maximum of 4.

Comment: You should do the general case, instead of only the specific case used to explain the problem.